# Centos VM- Insufficient free space (0 extentes) - This is on root (/)

Tags: centos

My `df -h` shows the following. When I use the command `lvextend -L12G` on this volume it says 1354 extents are needed.

```
FileSystem                      Size     Used         Avail  USe%  Mounted On
/dev/mapper/vg_viyengarvm-lv_root 6.5G    6.2G        42m    100%   /
```

What are my options to extend this?

Appreciate your help here.

Thanks
Venu

Answer (score 0):

You *may* have extra space, but your question does not provide the details needed to answer this completely.

The place to look is at the *partition size*, e.g., using `fdisk` or (better) the number of free physical extents (PEs) using `vgdisplay`.  Typically the numbers are rounded for readability (and include some overhead), so if your 12G was close, then reducing that to say 11.9G will work.  If it was not close, then you have to find the actual number of free physical extents.

Further reading:

- *[6.7. Insufficient Free Extents for a Logical Volume](https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Cluster_Logical_Volume_Manager/nofreeext.html)*
- [A Beginner's Guide To LVM - Page 2](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux_lvm_p2)

Comment: Total PE 1922; Allocated PE / Size - 1922 / 7.51 GiB Free PE /Size 0/0 I do n't have any space left. Since this is a VM running on windows, I want to extend this partiton as have more space on windows box. How can I do this. I have exceeded initial allocated size and I want to add more space.